# Python combinations with tuples

Tags: python, tuples, combinations

I have a list of tuples, one of the two items in the tuples is a number, I'm trying to get the list of all the tuples for which the sum of the numbers will be a specific sum. With itertools combinations I only get the list of numbers, not the list of tuples:

```
listInit= [("A",1), ("B",2),("C",3),("D",4)]

resultExpected=[ [("A",1),("D",4)], [("B",2),("C",3)] ] #target sum=5
```

With the following code:

```
listInit=[1,2,3,4]
result=[seq for i in range(len(listInit), 0, -1) for seq in itertools.combinations(listInit, i) if sum(seq) == 5]
print(result)
```

I'm getting:

```
result=[ (1,4), (2,3) ]
```

Which is the right results with numbers only, I'm not sure how to get a similar result with tuples.
Thank you in advance

Comment: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'` - the code that you gave us doesn't produce the output you say it does...

Comment: Sorry about that, I just edited the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would break out the list comprehension to make it easier to follow the flow of your code.

```
for seq in itertools.combinations(listInit, 2):
    print(seq)

=== Output: ===
(('A', 1), ('B', 2))
(('A', 1), ('C', 3))
(('A', 1), ('D', 4))
(('B', 2), ('C', 3))
(('B', 2), ('D', 4))
(('C', 3), ('D', 4))
```

So we can see that each seq has what we want - the pairs of tuples. Now you need to test whether the sum of the second elements is five.

```
for seq in itertools.combinations(listInit, 2):
    # seq is a tuple of tuples
    # so you want the second element of both outer tuples
    if seq[0][1] + seq[1][1] == 5:
        print(seq)

=== Output: ===
(('A', 1), ('D', 4))
(('B', 2), ('C', 3))
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense